# Core Data Boolean attribute compare

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I have a tableViewController, and in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I have this code:

```
    MinorGoal *minor = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (minor.finishedBoolean == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]){
    // code to make check mark
    UITableViewCell *indexPathCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    indexPathCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    NSLog(@"the %@, is finished", minor.title);
}
cell.textLabel.text = minor.title;
```

All what I want is to check the 'finishedBoolean' arrtibute for the 'minor' and if it's YES, then the cell it's in must have a check mark, when I run the code above I get the NSLog:

```
        NSLog(@"the %@, is finished", minor.title);
```

which means the if statement is working, but why the cell accessory isn't set to checkMark?which is this line:

```
        indexPathCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

Thanks, and sorry for newbie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the CoreData ManagedObject is the `minor` object which will make `finishedBoolean` an `NSNumber`.

Your check is failing because you are checking the that two objects ARE THE SAME OBJECT. The == does not check for equal values of objects.

There are several way to do that if statement.

```
if ([minor.finishedBoolean boolValue])

if ([minor.finishedBoolean isEqualToNumber:@YES])

if ([minor.finishedBoolean boolValue] == YES)
```

Out of all of these I'd pick the first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes this works, and it knows that boolValue is set to 'YES', but the cell accessory type isn't changed to check mark, this is the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Just use `cell.accessoryType = blah`, remove the "indexPathCell" code.